# Iterating the posts of wp_query gives me different order as what I am getting through the query or post's array itself

Tags: php, wordpress

I have implemented a WP_query function to get the data in wordpress. I iterate the available data ordered by 'modified', but when it is getting displayed on the screen, I get it ordered by alphabets rather than 'post_modified' field, I checked the query available in the results as well, I cannot see any other order by other than 'post_modified', below is the code:

```
$arrPostDtls = new WP_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'kiaarticles',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, //unlikely high
        'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'trash','draft','auto-draft'),
        'orderby' => array('modified' => 'DESC'),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'products',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'kiacategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $arrCTermSlug,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        )
        ));

 $strData = '
                <table id="id_'.$intPostId.'" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>                
                    </tr>
                </tfoot><tbody>';
             foreach ($arrPostDtls->posts as $arrPostDtlsVal) {

                $intResultpostId = $arrPostDtlsVal->ID;
                $strPostLink = get_permalink($intResultpostId);
                $strPostTitle = $arrPostDtlsVal->post_title;
                $strData.='<tr><td><a href = "' . $strPostLink . '">' . $strPostTitle . '</a></td></tr>';

            }
            $strData .='</tbody>
            </table>';


        echo $strData;
```

The result displayed is as below:

[image: Alphabetical Ordered List]

But we are expecting this order as per `post_modified` field of DB table column.

Below is the query I get in `$arrPostDtls->request`

```
SELECT ap_ac_posts.* FROM ap_ac_posts  INNER JOIN ap_ac_term_relationships ON (ap_ac_posts.ID = ap_ac_term_relationships.object_id)  INNER JOIN ap_ac_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (ap_ac_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ap_ac_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (40719,40935,40945,41762,41763,46525,46729,47308,49224,49377,49378,49379,49380,49381,49383,49649,49650) 
  AND 
  tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (40693,40956,41114)
) AND ap_ac_posts.post_type = 'kiaarticles' AND ((ap_ac_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR ap_ac_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR ap_ac_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR ap_ac_posts.post_status = 'trash' OR ap_ac_posts.post_status = 'auto-draft')) GROUP BY ap_ac_posts.ID ORDER BY ap_ac_posts.post_modified DESC
```

Please suggest what and where could be this order is being updated?

Comment: But in your query I didnt see post_modified column, maybe you should change it in 4-th line. modified to post_modified?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan the orderby with array('modified' => 'DESC'), is another way of using the order by for post_modified, wordpress reads 'modified' as post_modified

Comment: ok, can You print  $arrPostDtls->request to see query?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Query Updated in question

Comment: Thank you, after executing query do you get expected result in your order?

Comment: @VaheGalstyan Yes I do get the expected order, but when I iterate `$arrPostDtls->posts`, I do not get the expected order on UI, though the array of `$arrPostDtls->posts` is in order when I see the print of it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165130/discussion-between-om-the-eternity-and-vahe-galstyan).

Comment: Please first of all check the generated HTML source code, and verify what order the posts are in in there. (Just so that we can exclude the possibility that you have any client-side scripts running that re-order this data afterwards, or anything like that.)

Comment: @CBroe I found the response containing container is exposed to jQuery `DataTable()` plugin as `$("#someid").DataTable();`

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for enlightening me.. DataTable()'s default ordering was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Use orderby and order parameters separately in wp_quer arguments like

```
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'modified',
'order'   => 'DESC',
```

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );